# How to group multiple fields using rowspan grouping in primeng table

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I am using primeng data table for grouping rows and columns. For the row grouping, I could only group one field at a time with the example on official site

Here is my Html

```
<p-dataTable [value]="surveyMonitoring" rowGroupMode="rowspan" sortField="TenantName" [rows]="20" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[2,5,10,20]">
                                    <p-headerColumnGroup>
                                        <p-row>
                                            <p-column header="Tenant Name" rowspan="2"></p-column>
                                            <p-column header="Survey Name" rowspan="2"></p-column>
                                            <p-column header="Batch Name" rowspan="2"></p-column>
                                            <p-column header="Batch Status" rowspan="2"></p-column>
                                            <p-column header="No. of Ratees" rowspan="2"></p-column>
                                            <p-column header="Is Logged in?" colspan="2"></p-column>
                                            <p-column header="SelfAssessment" colspan="2"></p-column>
                                        </p-row>
                                        <p-row>
                                            <p-column header="Yes"></p-column>
                                            <p-column header="No"></p-column>
                                            <p-column header="Completed"></p-column>
                                            <p-column header="Pending"></p-column>
                                        </p-row>
                                    </p-headerColumnGroup>
                                    <p-column field="TenantName"></p-column>
                                    <p-column field="SurveyName"></p-column>
                                    <p-column field="BatchName"></p-column>
                                    <p-column field="BatchStatus"></p-column>
                                    <p-column field="RateeCount"></p-column>
                                    <p-column field="LoggedInUsers"></p-column>
                                    <p-column field="LoggedOutUsers"></p-column>
                                    <p-column field="CompletedAssessments"></p-column>
                                    <p-column field="PendingAssessments"></p-column>
                                </p-dataTable>
```

I want to group the first three fields i.e I want sortField attribute to accept an array.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, primeng datatables can only accept string for sortField. If you would like to change the parameter to an array, you should find the primeng/datatable.ts file and edit the Inpit() sortField property. Keep in mind that you should re-write the functions using that property also.

Comment: That should be a tedious job! Don't we have a solution that supports multi-row grouping in primeng datatable ?